# Python3.7 Vision API output to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am really new to python and i am using Google vision API to detect some text from image,In the API output there two thing which are of interest to me text and text.vertices both of them i have stored in two variables p & c  however i dont know how to create a single dictionary which i can then use to do some post processing(sorting,dicing etc.) on that data below is code i am using, could anyone please suggest any solutions

```
    for text in texts:
    if len(text.description) < 100:  
    p=text.description
    vertices = (['{}'.format(vertex.y)
                for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])
    c= vertices[0]  
    rpd={c:p}
```

However this creates seperate lines for each c & p i want everyting into a single dictionary so that i then sort it in ascending/descending

```
Actual output :{'562': 'MANUFACTURE'}
{'605': 'Net'}
{'604': 'Contents200m'}

desired output {'562': 'MANUFACTURE','605': 'Net','604': 'Contents200m')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your indentation first, as it is very tough to debug the loops in your code.

My intuition is that you are overwriting the 'rpd' dictionary every time the for loop is running. You probably want to define 'rpd' as dict() at the beginning of your for loop. Inside your for loop, you can set the key, value pairs for the dictionary.

```
                    rpd[c] = d
```

I would suggest you to try this once and print the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
rpd= {}
for text in texts:
    if (len(text.description) < 100) :  
        p=text.description
        vertices = (['{}'.format(vertex.y) for vertex in  text.bounding_poly.vertices])
        c= vertices[0]  
        rpd[c]= p
```

The above code should work.